# Listview ContextMenu Unclickable

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

So I have a `contextmenu` in my `xaml` code which is

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.Row="1" SelectionChanged="listView_SelectionChanged" IsEnabled="True">
        <ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Command="Delete" IsEnabled="True" Click="MenuItem_Click"></MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListView.ContextMenu>
</ListView>
```

and then in my `c#` code I have

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        listView.Items.Remove(listView.SelectedItems[0]);
        showList.RemoveAt(listView.Items.IndexOf(listView.SelectedItems[0]));
}
```

but unfortunatelly when I debug my program It won't let me click `contextmenu` delete button :( How can I solve this?

Comment: If I understand your problem correct way, once debugger kicked in your UI execution is halted until debugger returns (even you can find this behavior for duration of synchronous  program execution, isn't it?!) and hence you see your UI blocked. Based on your code, when you click on "Delete" item then only the debugger stops in event handler, right, so why do you want to click it again while in debug mode?